# Is there a way to have IntelliSense auto-complete, but not change what I've written?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-2022

The title.

I would like Visual Studio to auto-complete on any key press (and not only Tab), but only **add** to what I've written, never change it.

Is there a way to achieve that?

(VS2022 v. 17.4)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio has limited ability to modify how Intellisense works.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4ecfb382-d769-40af-908d-0bac9bd562d6/is-it-possible-to-change-intellisense-behavior-to-look-for-explicit-approval-of-suggestions?forum=visualstudiogeneral

You can also find the full documentation for it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-intellisense?view=vs-2022